# Differences between Extractors and Privacy Amplification for Quantum Random Generators

Tags: random-number-generator, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography, quantum-computing

We know that for the last step of QRNG: we need to separate quantum and classical noises from each other so we use extractors, after extractor we need privacy amplification step. At this point: if extractor is a strong extractor we can use it as a privacy amplification too. However I could not understand differences between extractor and privacy amplification. If I use the strong extractor for the second time, will I be able to complete my privacy amplification step? What will change in privacy amplification? If what happens, privacy amplification will be completed? Thanks

Comment: Don't know if this effects your question, but we don't /can't separate classic and quantum noises. Otherwise we could build totally 100% noise free systems.  The way to utilise the quantum noise in the presence of classical, it to ensure that the quantum signal far (?) exceeds the classical.

Answer (score 1):

Privacy amplification (PA) cannot be done at all with only a QRNG (which I take to be a quantum random number generator).  Privacy amplification resides further along the application stack, and requires two co-operating parties (Bob and Alice) and an opponent (Eve) listening in on their quantum channel within their quantum key distribution network (QKDN) :-

[image: qkdn]

Essentially privacy amplification (pink bits above) in QKDNs aims to allow two parties, Alice and Bob, to distil a secure final key from a partially secure bit string. The degree of security (bits) is governed by the Leftover Hash Lemma (LHL), which **also** can be applied to simple random number generation for regulating the output bias.

The purple rectangle is where true random numbers are generated within a QKDN.  Clearly within a QRNG that would be the end of the story. A randomness extractor may or may not be incorporated into the output stage of the QRNG as they're not always needed. If you did need a randomness extractor, they're used to alter the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) of the quantized signal into an almost perfectly uniform distribution.

That's a lot of stuff, so an example is probably in order.  See [High-speed Privacy Amplification Scheme Using
GMP in Quantum Key Distribution,](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340673454_High-Speed_Privacy_Amplification_Scheme_Using_GMP_in_Quantum_Key_Distribution) specifically §2.2.